# CSS animations for Log Cabin Window Glow

Tags: css, animation, effects, light

I am making a christmas themed site, I would like to make a log cabin style village. The main feature of this would be lights visible from the cabin windows.

I would just like to ask if anyone has an experience making realistic looking glow effects using CSS?

My current example simply fades an orange block in and out but I think this could to be made to look more atmospheric, i'm sure there is a cool trick for making nice glow effects that someone can share..

**Example:**
http://codepen.io/Jambob/pen/epMrBp

```
.animated {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 7s;
    animation-duration: 7s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes flash {
    0%, 50%, 100% {opacity: .80;}
    25%, 75% {opacity: 0.25;}
}
@keyframes flash {
    0%, 50%, 100% {opacity: .80;}
    25%, 75% {opacity: 0.25;}
}
.flash {
    -webkit-animation-name: flash;
    animation-name: flash;
}
```

**Example Of Lights:**
http://www.netanimations.net/deer-stream-cabin-snow-winter-animation.gif

Comment: have you tried using the `box-shadow` property? Depending on your target browsers you could use css animations to fade in/out too (I can't load your test site on my company network to see how you've done it thus far, maybe a jsfiddle would be good)

Comment: http://codepen.io/Jambob/pen/epMrBp

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LpdmbL added `box-shadow` usage example, rounded the edges slightly for a softer look and increased the animation speed while reducing the difference in states to give more of a "flickering from a fire inside" feel. Hope that puts you on the right path.

Comment: I like that, definitely gives the impression of flickering, I was thinking of also using a very transparent triangular shape which would go outside hitting the snow

Comment: http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_zgozwzj7VX0/TQpAuHI4v_I/AAAAAAAAAew/Puu-4D_F00E/s1600/Christmas_Wallpaper_Snow_Cabin_Lights.jpg

Probably the best example I can find

Comment: That would be a nice addition. If you don't need a gradient on the triangles, use the `border` method (nice generator here: http://triangle.designyourcode.io/). If you need a gradient on them it gets tricky - maybe a clipped rotated square div?

Answer (score 0):

Posting a summation of our discussion above here as an answer as I think this achieves everything you want.

Animate `box-shadow` to create the initial flickering glow from the windows. For drawing the ray of light from the windows casting out onto the snow, you'll actually need two triangles, one extending from the bottom edge of the window, the other from the right edge, joining together to create one shape.

You can create these triangles using a zero-width/height div and assigning it a border on two sides (this is well documented elsewhere, give it a search or use a generator like http://triangle.designyourcode.io/).

CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZbxRQy (I've done the first two-triangle ray for you, left the second window as an exercise so you can understand the technique yourself. I've also used `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements for the triangles to keep the DOM small, though you could equally use `div`s)

Comment: Should the triangular glows not have a higher z-index than the cabin? Thanks your for your help by the way

Comment: You're welcome. Child elements z-indexes are calculated relative to their parents. In other words, you shouldn't need to set the them, because they are already above the cabin. (Just noticed that there's a BG image. It doesn't show up for me because it's on your domain which my company's firewall blocks). So yes, the z-indexes need to be set to higher than that of the `#cabin` div, but do you need a z-index on that div anyway?

Comment: Just got access to your site, I can see what you mean now. In this case, the triangles need to be separate elements. Currently, as they are child elements of the window squares, which need to be behind the cabin, they cannot be brought in front of the cabin, no matter how high you set the z-index (because they are limited to their parents stacking context)

Comment: The way I see it:

Main lights hidden beneath cabin png (transparent windows)
Glow (light spillage) should be coming 'out' of the windows, at the moment the glow is also underneath the cabin due to inherited z-index

Comment: http://thisisdk.com/sites/default/files/content/project/work/norad_santatracker_0004_layer_comp_5.jpg

This is what I am trying to recreate